# How to detect input string characters language with build in .NET functionalities?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to detect if my input string has `Arabic` characters in it.
Maybe some code like this :

```
string str = "سS";
str[0].IsArabicCharacter(); //true
str[1].IsArabicCharacter(); //false
```

Currently using mapping but I want to migrate to some C# built in feature.

```
ArabicChars = "ساینبتسیکبدثصکبثحصخبدوزطئظضچج";
string str = "ل";
if(ArabicChars.Contains(str[0]) return true; else return false;
```

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, I have tried to use mapping. I'll add into my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best you're going to get is going to be the various RegEx unicode block character class: `\p{name}`

```
Regex.IsMatch(str[0], @"\p{IsThai}");
Regex.IsMatch(str[1], @"\p{IsArabic}");
```

MSDN Reference Pages:

- [Unicode Category or Unicode Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock)
- [List of supported named Unicode Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks)

Answer (score 2):

Get the Unicode value of a character and check to which chart it belongs:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 2):

Look at the unicode [Blocks.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Blocks.txt) file and decide which ranges you want to include as Arabic or Persian (U+0600..06FF is an obvious start) and do numeric comparisons.

Comment: @Mahdi - then, according to the Unicode consortium, Persian doesn't exist as a distinct alphabet. I don't know how you expect us to fix that for you.

Comment: I don't except to fix this. I'm looking for a solution if exist any; that's why I asked a question