# Identify language of characters in String in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

One of the functions in my web service receives data in different languages

1. Russian
2. Romanian
3. English
4. Arabic

I want to write a function that identifies the language that the characters in the received string belong to.

I have already found one for the Arabic language:

```
Public Function IsGenericArabic(ByVal Msg As String) As Boolean
    Dim ch As Char
    IsGenericArabic = False
    For Each ch In Msg
        Dim ch1 As Integer = CInt(AscW(ch))
        If ch1 >= &H621 AndAlso ch1 <= &H64A Then
            IsGenericArabic = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

But I can't find anything on how to identify **Russian** or **Romanian**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this a javascript library called franc could help you : https://github.com/wooorm/franc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect input string characters language with build in .NET functionalities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918376/how-to-detect-input-string-characters-language-with-build-in-net-functionalitie)

Comment: @Ammaroff Its a web service so Im only working server side.

Answer (score 2):

For many languages comparing single characters will not help. Think of all the languages using the Latin alphabet. For those languages you will have to detect words of this language. The problem is to find a list of words that will most likely occur in the input text. Full-text search algorithms usually exclude words which occur too often as those occur in most of the sentences and are therefore not selective enough. These are words like "and", "the", "a" and "of". Lists of such words are called stop-word lists. But this is exactly what we need here. Find stop word lists for all the languages that you want to detect (googling helps).

An algorithm then would look like this (in pseudo code, i.e. some details are missing):

```
Class LanguageInfo
    Public Property LanguageCode As String
    Public Property Words As HashSet(Of String)
End Class
```

---

```
Dim infoList = New List(Of LanguageInfo)()

'Prepare the language information
For Each language In { "rus", "rom", ... }
    'Assuming one stop word per line
    Dim stopWords() As String = File.ReadAllLines(language + ".txt")
    Dim info = New LanguageInfo()
    info.LanguageCode = language
    info.Words = New HashSet(Of String)(stopWords)
    infoList.Add(info)
Next

'Detect language of input
Dim bestLanguageGuess As String = ""
Dim maxWeight As Integer = 0
Dim inputWords() As String = SplitIntoSingleWords(input)
For Each info In infoList
    Dim weight As Integer = 0
    For Each w In  inputWords
        If info.Words.Contains(w) Then
            weight = weight + 1
        End If
    Next
    If weight > maxWeight Then
        bestLanguageGuess = info.LanguageCode
        maxWeight = weight
    End If
Next
If maxWeight > 0 Then
    bestLanguageGuess is the language we are looking for
End If
```